# go-swagger use a model for query parameters

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

According to the [docs](https://goswagger.io/use/spec/params.html) if we want to define query params as a struct we need to list every single operation that uses them after the struct.
This will prove exhausting for an API with hundreds of endpoints that all use the same query params that could change down the road.

Instead of adding

```
//  Parameters:
//      + name: limit
//        type: number
//        in: query
//        example: 500
//      + name: offset
//        type: number
//        in: query
//        example: 50
//      + name: sort
//        type: string
//        in: query
//        description: property sort order
//        example: +name
```

to every GET we have an editing it down the road we would like something along the lines of how models work

```
//      + name: query params
//        type: QueryParams
```

along with

```
// swagger:model QueryParams
type QueryParams struct {
    //in: query
    Limit int `json:"limit"`
    //in: query
    Offset int `json:"offset"`
    //in: query
    Sort string `json:"sort"`
}
```

although this does not appear to work with swagger:model or swagger:parmameters
is there any way to get a nice clean centralized query params without listing ever GET operation id next to the params struct?